# Subsonic + N-Tier and DDD

Tags: subsonic, domain-driven-design, n-tier-architecture

after hours of research i still don't know, which is the best way to build a n-tier ddd application with an ORM like SubSonic.

The projects structure should be similiar to the following:

1 - Presentation Layer (WPF MVVM)

2 - Application Layer

3 - Domain Layer -> where the Domain Entities/Business Entities are living (POCOs???)

4 - Infrastructure Layer -> Repositories + Models + Persistence + SubSonic

What i want is the following:

1. Using a Domain-Driven-Design approach
2. Using the Repository Pattern to abstract between Domain and ORM
3. Using SubSonic as ORM

My Questions are:

What will be the best way to accomplish this in combination with SubSonic? Which is the best way of using SubSonic (ActiveRecord, Repository, T4)?

Does it make sense to build the application structure in this specific way (in respect to the use of DDD in combination with SubSonic)?

Thank you for your answers and ideas.

krisan

Comment: SubSonic is only maintained by a few people. I would be weary of using it on a business critical application. nHibernate, LinqToSql and EF each have their pros and cons but are probably better long term bets than SubSonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that SubSonic **forces** you into a class per table model.  Those classes then are **not** suitable for using directly as Entities and Aggregates in DDD.  You can of course map between the SubSonic classes and your own domain model classes, but then using SubSonic isn't gaining you much.

Comment: Hi qes, thank you for your answer. That is what i expected, but not wanted to hear ;-) So does that mean that DDD is not really possible respectively it doesnt really make any sense to use SubSonic with DDD?

Comment: Do you know any other ORM that is as fast as SubSonic and fits better in a DDD Solution? It seems that e.g. nHibernate fits better?!

Comment: You can do it, but you will not want to use the SubSonic classes directly.  You would want to have your own Domain model classes and the SubSonic classes would not be exposed any higher than the Repository layer.  At that point, SubSonic is just a data access tool - and if that's all you're using it for I'd recommend a micro-orm like Massive, Dapper, or PetaPoco (really cool that one). Otherwise go the other way and use NHibernate that has the flexibility to map your DB to decent domain model classes directly.

Comment: The micro-ORM's are faster than SubSonic (be aware, there are some significant performance issue in SubSonic, especially LINQ), but you will still have to bridge from the ORM to the domain (not necessarily a bad thing, but more effort).  Otherwise, it's basically NHibernate.  LLBLGen might work, not familiar enough with it to be sure.  But I can say Linq2Sql and even still Entity Framework have design issues that will make doing DDD with them not a smooth path (vs. NHibernate).